# Conditional Exclusion Based on Substring

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

New to Python/Spyder and have a scenario where I have an existing list (we can call it **Model**). What I'm trying to do is to create another list based on this existing list, that captures the second-longest occurrence of each similar string. My original approach was to try and leverage the number of backslash occurrences, however, as you can see below this logic wouldn't work. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Code to generate existing list:

```
model = ["US\\Regional\\Ford\\F150", "US\\Regional\\Ford", "Europe\\UK\\England\\Aston Martin\\Vantage","Europe\\UK\\England\\Aston Martin","Asia\\Japan\\Honda\\CRV","Asia\\Japan\\Honda","Sweden\\Volvo\\XC70","Sweden\\Volvo\\"]
```

Desired new list:

| Make |
| --- |
| US\Regional\Ford |
| Europe\UK\England\Aston Martin |
| Asia\Japan\Honda |
| Sweden\Volvo |

Comment: Please show your code and the corresponding input / expected output.

Comment: Added code to show input values to list. "Desired output list" is my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Loop through each string in `model`. Call current string `str1`
- Check whether there is another string `str2` in `model` such that `str1` is a substring of `str2`.
- If yes, add `str1` to a new list `result`.

For example `"US\\Regional\\Ford"` is a substring of `"US\\Regional\\Ford\\F150"` so `"US\\Regional\\Ford"` is added to `result`.

```py
model = ["US\\Regional\\Ford\\F150",
         "US\\Regional\\Ford",
         "Europe\\UK\\England\\Aston Martin\\Vantage",
         "Europe\\UK\\England\\Aston Martin",
         "Asia\\Japan\\Honda\\CRV",
         "Asia\\Japan\\Honda",
         "Sweden\\Volvo\\XC70",
         "Sweden\\Volvo\\"]

result = []
for str1 in model:
    for str2 in model:
        if str1 in str2 and str1 != str2 : # is str1 a substring of str2 ?
# Also a string is a substring of itself so we have to exclude this edge case.
            result.append(str1)

print(result)
```

Output

```
['US\\Regional\\Ford', 'Europe\\UK\\England\\Aston Martin', 'Asia\\Japan\\Honda', 'Sweden\\Volvo\\']
```

Can you test it with different lists and let me know for which lists it does not work?

## Note

- If `model` contains `"US\\Regional\\Ford\\F150"` and `"US\\Regional\\Ford\\F150\\something"`, `result` will contain `"US\\Regional\\Ford\\F150"`
- You now have to replace "\\" in each string with "\"